# GWT RPC vs RPC Proxies in GXT

Tags: gxt, gwt-rpc

I'm brand new to GWT and GXT, so this might be a dumb question, but what advantages does RPCProxies in GXT provides over traditional GWT RPC. I know RPCProxies uses GWT RPC but if I'm fetching data to display in a TreeGrid, for example, why not do it with GWT RPC directly rather than using RPCProxy?

Comment: I would not use RPCProxies. Otherwise, if you want to change your widget-lib, you have to change the calls. Btw, I would recommend to use restful services f.e. restygwt

Comment: Oh, thanks. I'll try and implement everything using AsyncCallbacks.